# JSON::ParserError in ... unexpected token at '../../test.json' - RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been stuck on this for a while now.
I have my JSON (test.json) :

```
[
{
    "title" : "Star Wars",
    "Durée" : "3h",
    "Date" : "6 Mars",
    "Ratio" : "4.5/5"
},
{
    "title" : "Top Gun",
    "Durée" : "2h",
    "Date" : "17 Mai",
    "Ratio" : "4.3/5"
}]
```

I have my controller (food_controller.rb) :

```
class FoodController < ApplicationController

def index

    require "json"
    file = File.join "../../test.json"
    data = JSON.parse(file)
    
end
```

end

And i have this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVbUp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your json file is in the root directory of the project then try this:

```rb
require "json"

class FoodController < ApplicationController
  def index
    data = JSON.parse(File.read('test.json'))
  end
end
```

Otherwise if your file is in some directory `e.g. tmp` then just add this directory name as a prefix to the json file

```rb
data = JSON.parse(File.read('tmp/test.json'))
```